# How to create a username and password pop-up on Android

Tags: java, android

How can I create a custom dialog for entering username and password when I press any button on Android?

Comment: Come on people - if you're going to down-vote a question at least have the guts to write a comment!

Comment: Downvote for advertising the link

Comment: @Nick - good point. Downvoters and closers should be encouraged to explain their actions. Although I didn't vote it down, I did remove the self-promotion in the question (see the edits). The downvotes occured while said self-promotion was still part of the question.

Comment: this was so pure, unselfish  and innocent question....This shows he(@Onkar) is just a beginner in android and a fresher in stackOverflow....So no down votes..

Comment: Why are all of you taking downvotes *personally*? Read the tooltip: ""This question is unclear or not useful". Certainly doesn't seem like a completely far-fetched description of this question. (Also, @N-JOY, what is a "fresher"?)

Comment: By fresher i meant new comer. :-).

Comment: @ N-JOY yes i am fresher but m trying to do something and want success in that....so,please help me.

Comment: the answer posted by willytate dint help u?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Onkar,

You would probably want to built a custom `Dialog` with an `EditText` for name, and `EditText` for password with OK and Cancel buttons at the bottom.

You can read about creating a custom `Dialog` here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Good Luck